# Trouble installing rgdal package in R 3.3.0

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal

Trying to install rgdal package in R 3.3.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 using `install.packages("rgdal")` and getting the following error:

> In file included from
>   /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sp/include/sp.h:13:0,
>                    from rgdal.h:15,
>                    from OGR_write.cpp:11: /usr/share/R/include/S.h:41:3: error: #error S.h can not be used from C++ code: use R.h instead  #
>   error S.h can not be used from C++ code: use R.h instead

anyone else seen this and know how to fix it? Or do we need to wait for a fix to the `rgdal` package itself?

Comment: Just tried now and it worked, although I'm under Ubuntu 14.04. Maybe try to reinstall `sp` also before `rgdal`? Just a try, no great expectations.

Comment: That did the trick! Reinstalled sp package and rgdal installed cleanly afterward. If you want to put this into an answer, I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wild guess: you could try to reinstall `sp` before, just to have any dependency up-to-date.

Comment: Not OP, but I had the same problem and re-installing sp fixed the problem.